# Swift dynamic type checking for structs?

Tags: swift, dynamic, struct

I'm confused about dynamic type checking in Swift.

Specifically, I have a weirdo case where I want to, essentially, write (or find) a function:

```
func isInstanceOf(obj: Any, type: Any.Type) -> Bool
```

In Objective-C, this is `isKindOfClass`, but that won't work because `Any.Type` includes Swift structs, which are not classes (much less `NSObject` subclasses).

I can't use Swift `is` here, because that requires a hardcoded type.

I can't use `obj.dynamicType == type` because that would ignore subclasses.

The [Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html) seems to suggest that this information is lost, and not available for structs at all:

> Classes have additional capabilities that structures do not:
>
> ...
>
> - Type casting enables you to check and interpret the type of a class instance at runtime.

(On the Type Casting chapter, it says "Type casting in Swift is implemented with the is and as operators", so it seems to be a broader definition of "type casting" than [in other languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_casting_(computer_programming)).)

However, it can't be true that `is`/`as` don't work with structures, since you can put Strings and Ints into an `[Any]`, and pull them out later, and use `is String` or `is Int` to figure out what they were.  The Type Casting chapter of the Swift Book does exactly this!

Is there something that's as powerful as `isKindOfClass` but for any Swift instances?  This information still must exist at runtime, right?

Comment: FYI, more information on what you're actually trying to do would be helpful :)

Comment: I think I've distilled to pretty much just what I'm trying to do.  I've got some input that includes a type, and I want to (for example) filter an `[Any]` collection to just members of that type.  I can do it with a big if-else chain, or a switch statement that lists all possible types, but that's horribly ugly (not to mention redundant and un-reusable).  Additionally, I'm trying to learn how this all actually works in memory, because as written, the Swift Language book seems self-contradictory.

Answer (score 16):

Actually you can use `is` operator.

> Use the type check operator (is) to check whether an instance is of a certain subclass type. The type check operator returns true if the instance is of that subclass type and false if it is not.

Since `struct` can't be subclassed, `is` is guaranteed to be consistent when applied to instance of struct because it will check on it static type, and for classes it will query the dynamic type in runtime.

```
func `is`<T>(instance: Any, of kind: T.Type) -> Bool{
   return instance is T;
}
```

This work for both, `struct` and `class`.

Comment: That's a clever solution, but I'm still confused about Swift typing.  What does the Swift book mean, when it specifically says that "type casting" doesn't work with structs (and defines type casting as what you do with the "is" and "as" keywords), when you can use it with structs just fine?

Comment: *is* is not actually a type casting operator, is a reflective operator that give a little type info of an instance, *as* can be used in struct but not the way is used with classes, with struct you can use it if the variable is declared as *Any* contain an instance of struct A and you want to turn it into A again. And in classes you can use it to turn an object into any of it base class and possibly it subclasses, which is not possible with struct, Maybe that's the reason the book says that *as* don't work on structs.

Comment: Structs cannot be subclassed but they can adhere to protocols, so a struct cannot be cast to another type of struct because that's not possible, but it is possible they adhere to a protocol and so can be cast to a protocol. In this case, "Any"

Comment: xhamr: I think there's an issue of semantics here.  In any other programming language, I'd agree with you, but the Swift documentation uses "type casting" to mean additional things, e.g., "Type casting is a way to check the type of an instance" and "Type casting in Swift is implemented with the `is` and `as` operators".  I'm assuming that, despite the strange terminology, the Swift documentation is at least consistent between the top of the page and the bottom of the page.  :-)

Comment: I think what they're comparing to there is something like C based languages where you do `Type name = (Type) otherVar`, Swift does `let name = otherVar as Type`

Comment: to use your function Xcode gives: `'is'(instance: Any, of: τ_0_0.Type)`. and when using : `let str = "abc"
let mm = `is`(str, of:String.self) // true`. Any reason why Xcode returns the signature as such?

Comment: because if I write such: `func checkType<T>(_ instance: Any, of kind: T.Type) -> Bool{
    return instance is T
}` will return `checkType(instance: Any, of:T.Type)` as it's signature and doesn't have the weird `τ_0_0`. Overall is there **any reason you suggested to use *is* with the backticks?**

Answer (score 3):

As already stated, is/as should work fine with structs. Other corner cases can usually be done with generic functions, something like:

```
let thing: Any = "hi" as Any

func item<T: Any>(_ item: Any, isType: T.Type) -> Bool {
    return (item as? T) != nil
}

print(item(thing, isType: String.self)) // prints "true"
```

No idea if this fits your specific use case.

More generally, keep in mind that Swift (currently) requires knowing the type of everything at compile time. If you can't define the specific type that will be passed into a function or set as a variable, neither will the compiler.

Comment: This func is helpful (and clever), but I'm not sure what your last paragraph means.  In your example, `thing` has declared type `Any`, but the runtime must know more about it than that, because at runtime it's calling `item(item:isType:)` and checking its runtime type.  If I took user input, as either an Int or String, and passed it to that func, it does in fact tell me the type of it.

Comment: It won't tell you the type, but you could check if it was a string or an int. Keep in mind that "Any" is simply a protocol that structs/classes adhere to, so variables of type "Any" have no defined value.

Comment: Part of what I meant by the last part is that, in my example, all the Types in the function signatures are defined in the code. It's using generics to allow some dynamism in code, but at compile time the exact types are known for all uses of item(isType:)

Comment: Oh, I see.  I was wrong, then.  You can't call this `item<T>(item:isType:)` on user input of unknown type.

Comment: I think the key point that I missed in your answer here is that the Swift compiler requires knowing the value of the RHS of the `is` at compile-time, but not the LHS.  The part that's still confusing me is that it seems the runtime must still store "I'm a String" or "I'm an Int" with the struct value, somehow, but there's no way to access this, except via a (static) `is` expression.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're getting there. The way you have to do something like that in Swift is to try and cast the input to the different possible types.